# SQL Select sum price from two tables with two conditions on one syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, select, syntax, sum

I have two tables about Customer and Transaction.
I want to get two sums of price of each customer that has at least one record in table transaction. 
These results of price have different condition. But I want to show all in only one line.
How can I do?

P/s: I attached the picture of data:
[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. The most elegant, IMHO, would be a straight forward join according to the customer_id, and then summing over `case` expressions to handle the other conditions

```
SELECT   a.name, 
         SUM(CASE debit WHEN 131 THEN price) AS total_debit,
         SUM(CASE credit WHEN 131 THEN price) AS total_credit
FROM     customer a
JOIN     transactions b ON a.customer.id = b.customer_id
WHERE    131 IN (b.debit, credit)
GROUP BY a.name
```

Comment: No case `end` needed in MySQL?

Comment: @jarlh it's needed. That was a stupid typo in the total_debit, which was then copy-and-bugged to the total_credit. Thanks for noticing!